# How to retrieve specific fields of a Entity and cast them to another Entity

Tags: java, jpa

I have a use case for retrieving specific parts of Entity already defined in the persistence orm and I want it to be a new entity which contains part of these fields.

I know for Data Normalisation I should just extract those fields to the new entity, but unfortunately this is out of scope. There is also a lot of legacy connectors inserting the data into this format.

I thought I could simply use a TypedQuery of the new entity and create a named query to retrieve the specific fields of the old entity.

For Reference my example entity `StudentLessons` looks like this

```
String LessonId
String LessonName
String LessonRegistration
String StudentId
String StudentName
String StudentAge
```

I have created a new entity `Student`

```
String StudentId
String StudentName
String StudentAge
```

I want to retrieve a list of Students for a LessonId, note the Student is not being persisted and is only used for data transmission.

So I have created a Named Query inside `StudentLessons`

```
        <named-query name="StudentLessons.GetStudents">
            <query>SELECT SL.StudentId, SL.StudentName, SL.StudentAge FROM StudentLessons SL WHERE SL.LessonId= :LessonId</query>
        </named-query>
```

I have then created a method to retrieve the List of Students

```
    public List<Student> getStudents(Integer LessonId) {
        final EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        try {
            final TypedQuery<Student> query = em.createNamedQuery("StudentLessons.GetStudents", Student.class);
            query.setParameter("LessonId", LessonId);
            return query.getResultList();
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }
```

Whilst this successfully retrieves a list of students in the lesson it does not cast them to a Student.
Instead I get an error
`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not set java.lang.String field com.package.entity.Student.StudentId to [Ljava.lang.Object; (through reference chain: java.util.Vector[0]->Object[]["StudentId"])`

Is there anyway I can cast this result from the query to the intended Entity?

Note, in the example I Provided there are only 6 fields in the entity, in my actual project it is much more complicated which is why I want to transmit just the Students.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for are JPA result classes.
See https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select#Result_Classes_Constructor_Expressions

Essentially a JPA query retrieves an instance of the Entity configured in you JPA entity XML. If you want to retrieve another entity then you need to explicitly construct the object you want to retrieve in your select clause. In your case this would be:

> ```
> SELECT NEW Student(SL.StudentId, SL.StudentName, SL.StudentAge)
> FROM StudentLessons SL WHERE SL.LessonId= :LessonId
> ```

And you would need to create the corresponding constructor in the Student class.